# Angular js ng repeat with conditional ng class not applying css class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng repeat with a ng class that doesn't apply the css class in the case where my css class has a hyphen in the name:

```
<li
  ng-repeat="item in items"
  ng-class="{'i-someclass' : item.Id > 10}">
  {{item .name}}
</li>
```

Am I doing anything wrong? If I change the css class name to isomeclass it works.
AngularJS v1.0.7

Comment: Just check if angular is adding a class named iSomeclass.

Answer (score 9):

For me, your code works as is.

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pPd2aa?p=preview) that demonstrates the code.

**js:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = [

    { Id: 1, name: "item1" },
    { Id: 10, name: "item1" },
    { Id: 11, name: "item1" }
    ];

  });
```

**html:**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.4" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.4/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <ul>
      <li
        ng-repeat="item in items"
        ng-class="{'i-someclass' : item.Id > 10}">
        {{item .name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

**css:**

```
.i-someclass {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I think he is specifically talking about the verion 1.0.7 so the issue maybe in that version.

Comment: @Chandermani Ok, I updated the plunker link (it now is 1.0.7) and still works. :)

Comment: hi sorry for the long wait to reply, it does work on a simple controller, my description lacked a bit, I am using this code within a partial, so we have data-ng-include data-src="getMyPartial()" data-ng-show="getMyPartial()". getMyPartial is a method on the scope that loads the partial in, so I think the issue is when the above code is loaded in this manner through a partial.