# Add classes to adjacent elements dynamically on mouseenter

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

I'm creating a grid of elements and have a hover effect in place, using CSS transitions, for each element. I'd like to add secondary effects on adjacent x- and y-axis elements as well, creating a cloud effect. I imagine I'll be referencing those elements using jQuery's `next()` and `prev()` methods, or by $index and $parent.$index.

The grid area will be large enough to prevent row-wrapping (using negative margins and hidden overflow).

Here's a simplified example of my repeat:

```
<div class="activity-thumb-row" ng-repeat="i in getNumArray(20) track by $index">
    <div class="activity-thumb"
       ng-class="{'adjacent': adjacent}"
       ng-repeat="j in getNumArray(30) track by $index"
       ng-mouseenter="highlightActivities()">
    </div>
</div>
```

And a function in the controller (which I realize may not be the best approach):

```
$scope.highlightActivities = function() {
    $(this).next().adjacent = true;
    $(this).prev().adjacent = true;
}
```

**How can I target elements adjacent to the hovered element using ng-class (or something else) inside ng-repeat?**

[**Here's a fiddle for fiddling.**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/hxtdqps9/)

For reference, here are some related discussions:

- [Change class on mouseover in directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923111/angular-js-change-class-on-mouseover)
- [Angular js ng repeat with conditional ng class not applying css class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491974/angular-js-ng-repeat-with-conditional-ng-class-not-applying-css-class)
- [ng-mouseover and leave to toggle item using mouse in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532656/ng-mouseover-and-leave-to-toggle-item-using-mouse-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a directive that calculates all of the indices of adjacent cells and adds the adjacent class using jQuery only ... not ng-class.

Assumes that rows will wrap , would need adjusting for individual row elements

```
.directive('activityThumb', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function(scope, elem) {
      elem.bind('mouseenter', function(e) {

        var elW = elem.width(),
            $parent =elem.parent(),
            parentW = $parent.width(),
            $items = $parent.children(),
            numItems =$items.length
            itemsPerRow = Math.floor(parentW / elW),
            idx = elem.index(),
            rowIndex = idx % itemsPerRow;
        /* object of various indices , easy to inspect*/
        var adjacentIdx = {
          top:     idx > itemsPerRow ? idx - itemsPerRow : false,
          right:   rowIndex != itemsPerRow ? idx + 1 : false,
          left:    rowIndex > 0 ? idx - 1 : false,
          bottom:  (numItems - idx) > itemsPerRow ? idx + itemsPerRow : false
        }
        console.dir(adjacentIdx);
        $items.removeClass('adjacent')
        $.each(adjacentIdx, function(position, index){
          if(index !== false){
            $items.eq(index).addClass('adjacent');
          }
        });

      });
    }
  }

});
```

It wouldn't take much tweaking to remove jQuery dependency either.

Also would need additional directive on parent to remove extra classes when mouse leaves the main parent from one of the edges

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rke9e9eqY6nGS4vEpQUR?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: This looks good, too. I'm not following you regarding class removal, though. That already seems to be happening in your demo.

Comment: just if you move out of the parent from one of the edges

Answer (score 1):

First, it's not a good idea to deal with DOM elements in the controller.

Also, this problem seems to be mostly styling related, and not functionality related. I would thus try to keep the logic in the View and not in the controller.

There are 2 ways to deal with View-specific logic: 1) using custom directives or 2) View-defined scope variables

The second approach can work here and seems like the cheapest approach, but also a bit ugly. It `ng-init`s the `rowHighlight` array in the scope and sets which element is highlighted:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in getNumArray(20) track by $index" ng-init="rowHighlight = []">
    <div class="activity-thumb"
       ng-repeat="j in getNumArray(30) track by $index"
       ng-class="{'adjacent': rowHighlight[$index-1] || rowHighlight[$index+1]}"
       ng-mouseenter="rowHighlight[$index] = true" 
       ng-mouseleave="rowHighlight[$index] = false">
    </div>
</div>
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5copa8qn/)

Comment: Very nice. I'd love to see how you'd catch the y-axis elements as well. That's why I mentioned `$parent.$index`. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @isherwood, you can if you really insist, but it would only work on logical y-axis (i.e. if the elements wrap, it would not work) - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zn41p6re/). And of course it is now much uglier.

Comment: that's partly why I went for dom approach , since only one wrapper was originally declared which would be more suitable for responsive layout and can check items-per-row

Comment: @charlietfl, I agree that the DOM approach is cleaner and more powerful.

Comment: still like what you did though ... bitch to read ..but still cool

Comment: It wasn't clear from my question, but there won't be row-wrapping. I'm using negative margins and hidden overflow to create a masked area that's large enough for the rows to remain on a single line. Thanks to both of you for excellent assistance.