# Get the first Element that is floating on next line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of Elements that are floating left:

```
<style>
ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}
</style>
<ul>
  <li id="#one">One</li>
  <li id="#two">Two</li>
  <li id="#three">Three</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

...having a window width of 200px the first Element that is floating on the second line would be #three... having a window width of just 100px that would be #two.

Now on every `<li>` there is a click-event bound, that should tell me which Element is the first Element on the next Line, seen by itself.

Clicking on #one with a window width of 200px I want to get #three, and with a window width of 100px I want to get #two.

I tried to solve this by getting the position of the Element that is clicked on, query the Position inside the window using `.getBoundingClientRect()`, get the height of the Element (taking 20px here), and then get the Element by using `document.elementFromPoint(y,x)`...something like this:

```
y = clicked_element.getBoundingClientRect().left
x = clicked_element.getBoundingClientRect().top + 21
first_element_on_next_line = document.elementFromPoint(y,x)
```

so far, so good... but of course this is just working if the first element on the next line is really inside the window! :-\

and this is where I'm stuck...if I have a window width of 200px and a window height of just 20px (just for the example), I just can't select #three with `document.elementFromPoint()` because its position is outside the window.

I could also use jQuery, it's included anyways, but everything came across was using `document.elementFromPoint()`

Any Ideas??

Comment: Take a look at query.position: http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: I did something very similar to this a few days ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096039/add-classes-to-adjacent-elements-dynamically-on-mouseenter/28097130#28097130) . Was more complex because OP wanted all adjacent elements but might help you

Comment: @maja but jQuery.position() is just giving me the position of a specific Element, I can't query an Element with it...and I just want to iterate over the whole list of li's and check their positions...or am I totally blind??

Comment: can loop over `nextUntil()` and check position.top. First one that goes up is on next line

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for the Hint :-) thought of calculating the index by taking parent and childrens widths too, but I thought its a little too "complex" for this task...but maybe this is my way to go for this

Comment: would assume all heights are same. Any fluctations could change things due to float

Comment: @charlietfl yes, all heights are the same :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution I'm using now (which in fact is the Solution charlietfl brought up in the Comments) is this:

```
  $(function(){
    var list = $("ul"),
        lis = list.children(),
        first_li = lis.first(),
        list_width, first_li_width, items_per_line

    var set_vars = function(){
      list_width = list.width()
      first_li_width = first_li.width()
      items_per_row = Math.floor(list_width / first_li_width)
    }

    set_vars()

    lis.click(function(){
      index = lis.index(this)
      next_first_index = index + (items_per_row - (index % items_per_row))
      console.log(next_first_index)
    })

    $(window).resize(function(){
      set_vars()
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use following logic using jQuery `.position()` method: {as suggested by maja}

```
$(function () {
    var $lis = $('ul li').on('click', function(){
        var $nextFirstElement = $(this).nextAll('.first').first();
        console.log($nextFirstElement);
    });
    $(window).on('resize', function () { 
        var initialLeft;
        $lis.each(function(i){
            if (i === 0) { // this could be put out of the loop, but...
                initialLeft = $(this).position().left; 
            }
            $(this).toggleClass('first', i === 0 || $(this).position().left === initialLeft);
        });
    }).resize();    
});
```

### -jsFiddle-